How to react to service worker registration failed error in Angular pwa
I am using the @angular/service-worker for my PWA. My requirement is that the app should be usable only when a service worker has successfully installed. I used the following service :
export class ServiceWorkerRegistrationService {
  registered: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      if (!isDevMode()) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          this.registered.next(true); });
      } else {
        this.toastr.warning(
          'Service workers are not supported in development mode. Sync functionality will not work.',
          'Warning',
          {
            positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
          }
        );
        this.registered.next(true);
      }
    } else {
      this.toastr.warning(
        'Service workers are not supported in this browser. Sync functionality will not work.',
        'Warning',
        {
          positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
        }
      );
      this.registered.next(true);
    }
  }
}

I am using the registered behavior subject of this service in my app component to display a spinner when the subject has emitted false and display the App when it emits true. The problem is that if the app is in production mode and the SW registration fails the navigator.serviceWorker.ready promise never resolves . It also won't reject because according to documentation the ready property's value is A Promise that will never reject, and which may eventually resolve with a ServiceWorkerRegistration. So the app is stuck forever in that spinner. I want to show an error page instead which notifies the user that the app cannot be used right now.
I tried using the observables provided by angular's SwUpdate service like unrecoverable, but they don't trigger for the first SW registration. After inspecting the code I noticed that the navigator.serviceworker.register method is called in the generated main.js file and if the registration fails, it just logs the error to the console but does not rethrow the error. I tried to find some event related to this but couldn't. How can I achieve this ?
